# Cannot link to local script with "console_script" in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to setup the console_script option in setup.py so I can just write the name of a script to execute it from the CLI.

My package looks like this:

```
root
  |--bin
      |-- C2C (python file to execute)
  |--setup.py  
  |--(Rest of the package ... )
```

I have tried to add this to the setup.py file:

```py
   entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ['c2c = bin.C2C:main']
  },
```

And use `pip install -e .` from the root folder, but the function is linked to the location of my conda env instead of the root folder of the package, i.e. I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
<user>/anaconda3/envs/c2c_env/bin/c2c", line 5, in <module>
    from bin.C2C import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin'
```

How can I alter my setup.py file so that the terminal look for `root/bin/C2C` when I write `c2c` in stead of in `<user>/anaconda3/envs/c2c_env/bin/c2c`?

I have tried using:

```py
setup(
    ...
    scripts=['bin/C2C'],
    ...
)
```

Which can find `C2C` in the terminal, but if I change anything in C2C script, they are not reflected when only `C2C` is used (and it also messes up the relative paths inside the scripts, which are used to save results).

Comment: How does your complete call to `setup()` look like and what does "rest of the package" mean? Are you following the standard python flat or src layout?

Comment: @HansQ Sorry for not being clear on this, I'm quite new to this part of Python. The package I'm trying to change is this: https://github.com/StanfordMIMI/Comp2Comp 
and I want /bin/C2C to be available in the console (as something like "comp2comp" or "C2C")